# 403 Forbidden issues with Angular JS tutorial

Tags: apache, angularjs, mod-rewrite

I am trying to learn Angular JS using [this online tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/02/sample-application-with-angular-js/). I decided to download his test project to look at the file structure and how everything is working. The files are available from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/ccoenraets/angular-cellar):

I followed the instructions in the readme file but when I load the index page the Wine List fails to load due to a `403 Forbidden error`. I have a hunch that this might be due to either file permission or `mod_rewrite` issues but I don't know how to solve it.

I have looked through the `http.conf` file at `/etc/apache2/` and `mod_rewrite` appears to be enabled and I've also put a `phpinfo();` file in my root directory and looked for `mod_rewrite` in the enabled modules and it appears to be there.
Any ideas?

Comment: seems to be using some early versions of angular...may not be best learning resource as far as angular goes. Try tutorial on docs site. Doesn't send to server, but uses $http , and in higher sections $resource to load data

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time out to reply but I don't think its the age of this tutorial which is the issue. As I said I'm pretty sure its a file permissions or mod_rewrite issue which would affect me whichever tutorial I follow.

Comment: realize that...but a lot of substantial upgrades and feature additions have been made since version 0.9 not to mention early versions had some slightly different syntax in places I believe

Comment: Just tried this tutorial and getting the same 403 error: https://github.com/erkobridee/restful-bookmarks-phpslim

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache config file (httpd.conf or extras/httpd-vhosts.conf) add:

```
<Directory "C:/path/to/files">
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Use your actual path, this will grant Apache access to the directory.

Comment: Hi Wayne, this lead to me getting:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through a few of the related questions I found a solution:

Adding the following to my vhost file did the trick:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

I hope this helps someone else!